# Class inheriting after IdentityUser, can't get acces to IdentityUser class properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have class inheriting after IdentityUser.

```
public class CatalogUser : IdentityUser
```

My class "Movie" got property.

```
public CatalogUser CatalogUser { get; set; }
```

Now i am trying to use IdentityUser properties in any view like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CatalogUser.Email)
```

Can't get acces because CatalogUser hasn't Email field, IdentityUser has.

How to solve this?

I disabled proxyCreation, if it is important.

Comment: I managed i did smth wrong, i need to read about usermanager and userstore.

Comment: It seems there's no email field in the 'IdentityUser' in the latest version of ASP.Net Identity, but you can add yours to the 'CatalogUser' class.